# Make content of navbar fit when the screen is between 768px and 992px

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Whenever I resize my browser the content of the navbar gets pushed to a newline. This only happens between 768px and 992px. Is there a way that I can make the content of the navbar fit my screen?

This is what happens when the screen is between 768px and 992px:

[image: http://image.prntscr.com/image/93ddcadd374d4af9928e3be209645ab3.png]

## HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logo</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- <li class="active"><a href="#">Main <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li> -->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                           aria-expanded="false">dropdown 1<span
                                class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/news">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/staff"> 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/status">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/about">4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                           aria-expanded="false">dropdown 2<span
                                class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.lunarirc.net:+6697/?nick=lunar%7C?#LunarIRC" target="_blank">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="irc://irc.lunarirc.net:6697">                         2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                           aria-expanded="false">dropdown 3<span
                                class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                           aria-expanded="false">dropdown 4<span
                                class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                           aria-expanded="false">dropdown 5<span
                                class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                           aria-expanded="false">dropdown 6<span
                                class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                   
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

## CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #2c3e50;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
        color: #18bc9c;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
          display: block;
      }
    .navbar {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 65px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    .panel {
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #1a242f;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transition: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav>li>a {
    padding-right: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #fff;    
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #18bc9c;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #18bc9c;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1a242f;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #1a242f;
}

.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 400px;
}

.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

Try it out at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbEOya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also remove the padding from other elements evenly as well .

Code pen : http://codepen.io/saa93/pen/vyEWaO

Code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 992px)  {
  .navbar .container{
   width:100%; 
  }

   .nav.navbar-nav > li > a {
   padding-right: 8px;
   }
  a.navbar-brand{
    padding-right:20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works now for the `navbar-brand` but `dropdown 6` still gets pushed down.

Comment: did you check the code pen link ?  i dont see it pushed down untill it collapses. I wonder if any other css is taking precedence over this one. Did you update your code pen ? can i check it there.

Comment: Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbEOya it happens when i resize my browser, I also tried it locally the `dropdown 6` gets pushed down.

Comment: answer updated , i removed little more of padding for li elements its 8px instead of 15px. 
Code pen updated: http://codepen.io/saa93/pen/vyEWaO

Answer (score 0):

Use the below media css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:992px) {
.nav > li > a {
  padding-right: 7px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional media would be good:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
.navbar-nav>li {
width: 112px;
}
}
```

I would do it this way:
http://codepen.io/abokhalel2/pen/aBzEog

Part of the code is credited to Saa_keetin